# Show that $pq$ ($pq\neq6$) is deficient.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $pq$ ($pq \ne6$) is deficient.

This means I need to show that $\sigma(n)-n<n$ or that $\sigma(pq)-pq<pq$. Since $\sigma(pq)=\sigma(p)\sigma(q)=(p+1)(q+1)=pq+p+q+1$ and so $\sigma(pq)-pq=pq+p+q+1-pq=p+q+1$. We must then show that $p+q+1<pq$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Say $p\lt q$. Because $pq\neq 6$, $q\geq p+2$. How does $pq$ compare with, say, $q+q$?

Comment: This is about $\sigma(n)$, the sum of the divisors of $n$.

Comment: If we assume $2 \le p < q$ then $p + q + 1  \le 2q \le pq$.  Surely if $p, q$ aren't one then the sum of them is less than the product of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $p+q+1 < pq$ is equivalent to $(p-1)(q-1) > 2$.

WLOG suppose $2 \le p < q$. Then we just need to prove $q-1 > 2$.

Comment: They are primes, I meant to include that. Usually $p$ and $q$ denote primes when dealing with $\sigma(n)$.

Comment: @fleablood: From $\sigma(pq) = \sigma(p)\sigma(q) = (p+1)(q+1)$ I was able to deduce that $p,q$ are *distinct* primes.

Comment: This is really clever. I can see this. What does it take to be able to see things like this in advance? Just practice or assuming the inequality is true and seeing that it leads you to something obvious and then you know it's true from the start?

Comment: This trick is called "Simon's Favourite Factoring Trick", or SFFT. I try to use this whenever I see $pq, p, q$ in the same equation/inequatity.

Comment: @player3236 thank you so much, I'll check it out.